# SQL: Show Records Once SUM Threshold Is Reached

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, sorted on a date value (ASC).

```
+----+------------+-------+
| Id |    Date    | Value |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2018-01-01 |    10 |
|  2 | 2018-01-02 |     5 |
|  3 | 2018-01-03 |    15 |
|  4 | 2018-01-04 |     0 |
|  5 | 2018-01-05 |     5 |
|  6 | 2018-01-06 |    10 |
|  7 | 2018-01-07 |     5 |
|  8 | 2018-01-08 |     0 |
|  9 | 2018-01-09 |     0 |
| 10 | 2018-01-10 |    10 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

I would like to create a view that only returns the records once the SUM of the Value is higher than 30, starting from the first record.
So my threshold is 30, every record with a value that fits in the first 30 should be hidden.
All records that follow once this threshold is reached, need to be shown.

This means that my required result looks like this:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| Id |    Date    | Value |
+----+------------+-------+
|  4 | 2018-01-04 |     0 |
|  5 | 2018-01-05 |     5 |
|  6 | 2018-01-06 |    10 |
|  7 | 2018-01-07 |     5 |
|  8 | 2018-01-08 |     0 |
|  9 | 2018-01-09 |     0 |
| 10 | 2018-01-10 |    10 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

As you can see, Id's 1, 2 and 3 are left out, because their values (10, 5 and 15) SUM up to 30.
Once this threshold is reached, the remaining records are visible (even the 0 value of Id 4).

I've created some scripts to setup a test table with data:

```
-- Create test table
CREATE TABLE thresholdTest (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Value] INT NOT NULL
)

-- Insert dummies
INSERT INTO [thresholdTest] ([Date],[Value])
VALUES
('2018-01-01',10),
('2018-01-02',5),
('2018-01-03',15),
('2018-01-04',0),
('2018-01-05',5),
('2018-01-06',10),
('2018-01-07',5),
('2018-01-08',0),
('2018-01-09',0),
('2018-01-10',10);

-- Select ordered by date
SELECT *
FROM [thresholdTest]
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
```

All I need is a SELECT statement / view.
The threshold is always static (30 in this example).
The data could ofcourse differ, but it's always sorted on a Date and includes a Value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your table isn't sorted on the date value unless a clustered index is created on that column. It's simply sorted on the return using the `order by` as you have written. I just want to highlight this is very different and many people mistakenly think their data is sorted on disk in the order it is inserted. Without a clustered index, this isn't true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a window function:

```
;with cte as(
select *,  tot = sum([Value]) over (order by [Date])
from thresholdTest
)

select 
   Id, 
   [Date], 
   [Value]
from cte
where 
    (tot >= 30 and [Value] = 0)
    or tot > 30
```

Comment: Your query will ignore `4 | 2018-01-04 |     0 ` :) this row

Comment: Thank you scsimon! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `SUM` with *window function* in subquery to accumulated `totle` then write condition in main query.

```
select Id,
      Date,
      Value
from 
(
  SELECT *,
         SUM(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Date) totle
  FROM thresholdTest
) t
WHERE totle > 30 OR (Value = 0 AND totle = 30)
```

**[Results]**:

```
| Id |       Date | Value |
|----|------------|-------|
|  4 | 2018-01-04 |     0 |
|  5 | 2018-01-05 |     5 |
|  6 | 2018-01-06 |    10 |
|  7 | 2018-01-07 |     5 |
|  8 | 2018-01-08 |     0 |
|  9 | 2018-01-09 |     0 |
| 10 | 2018-01-10 |    10 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27626/6)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it

```
select t1.id, t1.Date,t1.Value
from [thresholdTest] t1
inner join [thresholdTest] t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.value, t1.Date
HAVING SUM(t2.VAlue)>30 OR( SUM(t2.value)=30 AND t1.value=0)
```